# Eliminate #Error within Report Builder 3.0 when dividing by 0

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

When the following formula divides by 0, all three of the below are returning `#Error`

```
=(Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value))/(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value))

=IIf(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)=0,"",(Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value))/(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)))

=IIf((Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value))=0 Or (Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value))=0," ",(Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value))/(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)))
```

What do I need to do to eliminate `#Error`?  Why isn't report builder following the true condition?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that ReportBuilder still tries to evaluate the false path, even if the condition resolves to true. The command below should solve your problem.

```
 =IIf(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)=0,0,Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value)/IIf(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've just had this problem and it was driving me insane. Does it make any sense that devs wrote the function to evaluate this way?

Comment: @MattHall I'm guessing that it's not a conscious design decision, but rather an unintended consequence of the way they implemented their expression evaluation parser/engine.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is missing one parenthesis it should be

```
 =IIf(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)=0,0,Sum(Fields!Q2ActDelta.Value)/IIf(Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!Q1Actuals.Value)))
```

Comment: I've added the missing parenthesis to [the above answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24793768/3558960). Could've just left me a comment...